# Probability of finding particle in infinite square well, displaced walls

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, potential

Initially a quantum particle moves in a one-dimensional well ($x$-axis) from $-a$ to $ a$, $ V = \infty $ outside and $ V = 0 $ inside the well.

So initially, the wave-function $$ \psi_0 = \sqrt\frac{1}{a} \sin(\frac{n \pi x}{2a}) $$for $n$ = even, and a cos-function for $n$ = odd.

The particle is in the ground state, and the walls are now instantaneously displaced such that the well is from -3a to 3a.

How do you know calculate the probability of measuring the two lowest excited states after this instantaneous displacement?

I'm not sure how do this, would you use $\psi_0$ and calculate the probability by integrating $| \psi_0 |^2$ (for $n = 1$ and $ n = 2$) from $-3a$ to $3a$, or do you need to define a new wave-function?

Answer (score 1):

There are two important points to keep in mind when working through this problem.

(1) Since the Hamiltonian for the system changes suddenly, the wavefunction just after the change is the same as the wavefunction just before the change.

(2) Then energy eigenstates after the change are different from the energy eigenstates after the change.

It follows that, though the wavefunction corresponds to an energy eigenstate before, it does not after.

In other words, the wavefunction after the change is a superposition of the *new* energy eigenfunctions.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I understand what you have written about the Hamiltonian changing, but I don't quite understand what you mean by the new wavefunction being a superposition of the new energy eigenfunctions. How does that help me going towards calculating the probabilities? Or how would you quantify the new energy eigenfunctions?

Comment: @Alexander, in your question you asked *"How do you calculate the probability of measuring the two lowest excited states after this instantaneous displacement."*  So, you know the wavefunction of the system just after the change, and you know (or ought to know) the energy eigenfunctions after the change.  This is all you need to answer the quoted question.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean I ought to know the 'energy eigenstates' after the change (as the wavefunction is the same).

E = (n^2 pi^2)/(8mL^2), so that when L changes from a to 3a, a different value of E is given. I don't understand then how this relates to the probability, because if the energy before and after has no known relation, that means the constant n (excited state level) can't be changed to reflect the energy change, so what does change?

Could you explain how I use the energy eigenvalue afterwards?

Comment: @Alexander, yes you know the new energy eigenfunctions and you know the wavefunction (immediately after the change) so the probability amplitude of finding the system in one of the new energy eigenfunctions is given by the inner product of the wavefunction and that energy eigenfunction.  This is elementary QM.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_function#Position-space_inner_products